# border on td tag on hover using css moves whole table

Tags: html, css, hover, border, html-table

I was testing this on fiddle:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="changeme">something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="changeme">something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="changeme">something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="changeme">something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this css:

```
.changeme:hover {
    border:outset;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I just wanted to create a little popping out like effect on the td tag but it has this weird wavy effect when you run the mouse up and down the column, how could I remove that?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `outline` instead of `border` property, which would suit better in this particular scenario

```
.changeme:hover {
    outline:2px solid #f00;
    padding:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5HdW/4/)</kbd>

Why using `border` causes that offset? If you are aware of [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html), the `border` is counted outside the element instead of inside, and thus it shakes your element on hover.

[image]

There are various ways to solve this issue, one can also use `transparent` border color to reserve the border space like

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H5HdW/5/)</kbd>

```
.changeme{
    padding:2px;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.changeme:hover {
    border:2px solid #f00;
    padding:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Not way to contact you other then this so sorry for the comment but [**join this chat room**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50548/i-choose-you-mr-alien) when you can.

Answer (score 3):

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/H5HdW/3/)

Try doing:

```
.changeme{
    padding:2px;
}
.changeme:hover {
    border:2px outset;
    padding:0;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

The 'pop' is happening because the width of the border is being added on hover, offsetting the other table cells. To counteract this, set padding on a cell the same as the width of the border you wish to apply, then remove on hover. The border will then fill this space seamlessly, keeping the table structure in place.